# Getting CSV sheet name with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

Is there something similar or equivalent to get CSV file sheet name, such as pd.ExcelFile(file), sheet_names, for excel files?

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)

xl.sheet_names
```

Comment: CSV is a text file. It doesn't have sheet names. Note that any CSV you open in Excel will automatically have only one sheet named 'Sheet1'.

Comment: As pavel mentioned, in CSV files you have only one sheet

Comment: @pavel You are right, that is what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@pavel, answered the question, thanks guys.
CSV is a text file. It doesn't have sheet names. Note that any CSV you open in Excel will 
automatically have only one sheet named 'Sheet1'. – pavel Jun 12 at 2:38

Answer (score -1):

Get the name of the sheets in the workbook:

```
path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/ABC.xlsx"

xl_file_name = pd.ExcelFile(path)

print("Following are the sheets available in the workbook: " + str(xl_file_name.sheet_names))
```

You will be able to see the name of the sheets in the workbook now.

Answer (score -2):

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('file.xls')

print(xl.sheet_names)  # see all sheet names
```

Comment: The question was about csv file, which don't have a concept of a 'sheet name'.

Comment: If I might, OP may also be thinking along the lines of opening in Excel, in which case, Excel assigns the file name minus the extension to be the sheet name.